# Penetrating a drywall ceiling; NM in conduit or NM not in conduit?

Tags: wiring

I have an outlet box (a simple receptacle box, not a cabinet, cutout box, or meter socket box, so I don't see 312.5 applying to this) surface mounted on the block wall of my garage.  Then I have NM cable in EMT (for physical protection) leaving the box going up the block wall.  I have a drywall ceiling in the garage.  I want to go through the dry wall ceiling and go on my merry way with just the NM cable.  My question is:  How do I go through the drywall ceiling?  Do I have to stop the EMT short of the ceiling and go through the ceiling with the just the cable?  (Of course, I'll seal around the cable)  Or, do I go through the drywall ceiling with the EMT and then exit the EMT in the attic?  (The attic is unfinished, no floor or anything.)

Answer (score 3):

The cable needs to be protected at least 8' up the wall if left open. I usually run the emt through the ceiling even if taller for looks then put a bushing on the end and run the cable normally.

Answer (score 2):

Go ahead and have the EMT penetrate the ceiling, then use an EMT-to-NM transition fitting in the attic where the EMT ends:

[image: EMT-to-NM transition coupling]